# Conditionally Add to Cart redirect based on products IDs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am trying to get all products to redirect to one custom page EXCEPT for 3 products which go to Checkout (this part works).

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {

        if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || ! is_numeric( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
            $url = get_permalink( 16 ); // URL page ID to redirect for all pages but below mentioned        
            return $url;
        }

        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) );

        // Only redirect the product IDs in the array to the checkout
        if ( in_array( $product_id, array( 999, 997, 872) ) ) {
            $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
        }

        return $url;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make your code working as expected, is very simple. Below I have change a little bit your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {

    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) );

    // Only redirect the product IDs in the array to the checkout
    if ( in_array( $product_id, array( 999, 997, 872) ) ) {
        // This is more correct to get the checkout URL
        $url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id') );
    } else {
        // All other products that are not in your array will be redirected to this URL
        $url = get_permalink( 16 ); // URL page ID to redirect for all pages but below mentioned
    }   
    return $url;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.